# Telerik mvc grid Ipad issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

I am working in an MVC 3.0 application. In my project I used Telerk mvc grid for data listing. I made grid edit mode as "InCell". In my grid, there are two columns "Facts" & "Actions". When I press "Facts" column it changed into edit mode with textbox. Also in Ipad, keypad get displayed automatically. There after when I press "Actions" column, it changed into edit mode but Ipad keypad hides. If I am pressing same "Actions" column or any other column again, Ipad keypad get displayed. But in the online demo of telerik mvc grid batch editing (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid/editingbatch) it seems working. I am using telerik version 2012.2.607 in my project. My code for grid listing looks like.

```
    @(Html.Telerik().Grid<AnswerQuestionVM>()
    .Name("GridQuestions")
    .DataKeys(keys =>
    {
        keys.Add(p => p.QuestionID);
    })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(p => p.QuestionNumber).Format("{0:0.00}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center;" }).Title("#").Width("5%").ReadOnly();

        columns.Bound(p => p.QuestionName).Title("Question Name").Width("43%").ReadOnly();

        columns.Bound(p => p.Facts).Width("8%");

        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<img src='" + @Url.Content("~/images/help.gif") + "' name='help' alt='help' title='<#=FactOptions#>' />");

        columns.Bound(p => p.Actions).Width("8%");

        columns.Template(@<text></text>).Width("2%").ClientTemplate("<img src='" + @Url.Content("~/images/help.gif") + "' name='help' alt='help' title='<#=ActionOptions#>' />");

        columns.Template(@<text></text>).Title("Skip").Width("3%").ClientTemplate(
        "<# if(Skip==false) {#>" +
        "<input type='checkbox' style='cursor:pointer;' class='skipClass' />" +
                 "<#} else{#>" +
        "<input type='checkbox' style='cursor:pointer;' class='skipClass' checked='checked' />" +
        "<# } #>"
        );

        columns.Bound(p => p.Note).Title("Note").Width("26%");

    })
         .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.GridEditMode.InCell))
         .KeyboardNavigation( navigation => navigation.EditOnTab(true))
         .ClientEvents(e => e.OnSave("OnSave"))
         .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
         {
            dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetQuestion", "AnswerQuestion", new { Area = "question",  ajax = true }).Enabled(true);
         })
                                                                                              .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(false))
                                                                                             .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
                                                                                             .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true))
                                                                                             .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))
                                                                                             .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled(false))
                                                                                             .Footer(true)
                                                                 )
```

Please tell what I am missing in my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If i were you i would write prototype with code in telerik example, and confirm that it works on IPAd properly. Then iteratively transform it in your grid (with mocks in everywhere exclude interface) wtih confirmation of working it on IPad on every iteration.